# equation of lines goes through origin

Tags: geometry

suppose  that we are require to write equation of lines,whose  go through origin and  distance from point $F(-4,3)$  to this line is  $1cm$

first of all   ,distance from point $F(x_0,y_0)$  to line $A*x+B*y+C=0$  is
   $d={+,-}(A*x_0+B*y_0+c)/(\sqrt{(A^2+B^2)})$
because we have origin,we have $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$
equation of line is  $y=k*x$  or   $k*x-y=0$ if we put point $F(4,-3)$  ,i have got  $K_1=-2/15*(6+\sqrt{6})$ and $k_2=2/15*(\sqrt{6}-6)$
or
$y_1=-2/15*(6+\sqrt{6})*x$
and 
$y_2=2/15*(\sqrt{6}-6)*x$
is that correct or did i make some mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line on the plane through the origin $\,\Longrightarrow mx+y=0\,$ , and we want the distance from the given point to be $\,1\,$: $$\frac{|-4m+3|}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}=1\Longrightarrow 15m^2-24m+8=0\Longrightarrow m_{1,2}=\frac{12\pm 2\sqrt{6}}{15}$$not very nice solutions but nevertheless, solutions.

Since I can't fully understand your solution (please use LaTeX to write mathematics!) I can't be sure whether you got them right...but the signs look fishy there.

Comment: yes  equation i have got the same,just you are right my  answer seems  a little  tricky because of  LaTeX

Comment: @Dato, yes: I already checked what I think your answer is and it looked fine. You already used the "$" signs, but you didn't use the functions, for example "\frac{}{}" to do fractions...